# Running a PowerShell script in SQL Server Agent is not working

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2012, sql-agent-job

I have a SQL Server Agent job that runs a PowerShell script to pull data from a database and save it in a csv file.

The job type is set to `PowerShell` and the command looks like this:

```
$sql=@'exec my_stored_procedure'@
$result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance INSTANCE_NAME -Database DBNAME -Query $sql
#The first row gets removed and then save it to a csv file
$result | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content \\SERVER\c$\Folder\file.csv
```

When I run this job, it runs successfully, but the `file.csv` is not created in the specified location.

I checked the Job History and it says:

> The job script encountered the following errors. These error did not
>   stop the script:  (.....) The corresponding line is   `$result |
>   ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content
>   \\SERVER\c$\Folder\file.csv`. Correct the script and reschedule the
>   job. The error information returned by PowerShell is `'Cannot use
>   interface. The IContentCmdletProvider interface is not implemented by
>   this provider.'`. Process Exit Code 0.

Could someone help me understand what I'm missing?
This is my first PowerShell project, so I'm probably missing things that are obvious to other people..?

Comment: Any particular reason you are using SQL to run PowerShell to connect to SQL? Why not just run the procedure from there and export it? Perhaps use SSIS depending on your needs.

Comment: @Matt I have other jobs that need to run before the PS script, so I was hoping I could run the PS as a part of SQL server agent job steps.

Comment: Why don't you try PowerShell `Export-Csv` cmdlet.
`$result | Export-Csv -path \\SERVER\c$\Folder\file.csv -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: @VivekKumar With `Export-Csv`, I get a new error message `Cannot perform operation because operation "ReportWrongProviderType" is invalid. Remove operation "ReportWrongProviderType", or investigate why it is not valid."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it was complaining because of the server name in the path.

I originally had:

```
ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | 
    Select-Object -Skip 1 | 
    Set-Content  \\SERVER\c$\Folder\file.csv
```

but CDing to the directory and specifying the file did the trick:

```
$directoryPath = "C:\Folder"
cd $directoryPath
ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | 
    Select-Object -Skip 1 | 
    Set-Content  C:\Folder\file.csv
```

Comment: This seems to be a solution. I referred to this [link](https://mattypennysite.wordpress.com/2015/11/19/powershell-error-cannot-perform-operation-because-operation-reportwrongprovidertype-is-invalid/).
Not sure what's the root cause here, but it does the trick somehow.